# How to reposition title in seaborn.FacetGrid if tight_layout is applied?

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I have a simple seaborn *FacetGrid()* with barplots inside.

I applied *tight_layout()* to my final plot, as xticks had to be properly positioned on the plot after rotation.
As result, when I want to add the title to the plot it is positioned in the wrong place, basically over the existing axes.

So, my **question** is how should the title be manipulated in order to be properly positioned in case *tight_layout()* is applied?

I reproduced the issue with the standard tips dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

days_dict = {day:day+', a long name' for day in tips['day'].unique()}
tips['day_long'] = tips['day'].map(lambda x: days_dict[x])

grid = sns.FacetGrid(tips,col='size',col_wrap=3,height=4,sharex=False)

grid.map(sns.barplot, 'day_long', 'total_bill').set_titles('{col_name}')
grid.fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
grid.fig.suptitle('Title (it should be placed higher)',fontsize=16)

for ax in grid.axes.flat:
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add (adjust the value to your taste)

```
grid.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.90)
```

after `tight_laout()` to make some room at the top of the plot for the `suptitle()`